# Compute a value using multiple preceding rows

Tags: apache-spark

I have a `DataFrame`, that contains events ordered by timestamp.
Certain events mark the beginning of a new epoch:

```
+------+-----------+
| Time | Type      |
+------+-----------+
| 0    | New Epoch |
| 2    | Foo       |
| 3    | Bar       |
| 11   | New Epoch |
| 12   | Baz       |
+------+-----------+
```

I would like to add a column with epoch number, that, for simplicity, can be equal to the timestamp of its beginning:

```
+------+-----------+–------+
| Time | Type      | Epoch |
+------+-----------+-------+
| 0    | New Epoch | 0     |
| 2    | Foo       | 0     |
| 3    | Bar       | 0     |
| 11   | New Epoch | 11    |
| 12   | Baz       | 11    |
+------+-----------+-------+
```

How can I achieve this?

The naive algorithm would be to write a function that goes backwards until it finds a row with `$"Type" === "New Epoch"` and takes its `$"Time"`. In case I know the maximum number of events within an epoch, I can probably implement it by calling `lag()` that many times. But for the general case I don't have any ideas.

Comment: I fail to see why you couldn't just group by epoch and perform your operations over each group.

Comment: I have a feeling I'm missing something obvious. How can I group the first table by epoch? I don't know how to find out what epochs Foo, Bar and Baz belong to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is my solution. Briefly, I create a dataframe that represents epoch intervals then join it with original dataframe.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val ds = List((0, "New Epoch"), (2, "Fo"), (3, "Bar"), (11, "New Epoch"), (12, "Baz")).toDF("Time", "Type")
val epoch = ds.filter($"Type" === "New Epoch")
val spec = Window.orderBy("Time")
val epochInterval = epoch.withColumn("next_epoch", lead($"Time", 1).over(spec))//.show(false)
val result = ds.as("left").join(epochInterval.as("right"), $"left.Time" >= $"right.Time" && ($"left.Time" < $"right.next_epoch" || $"right.next_epoch".isNull))
      .select($"left.Time", $"left.Type", $"right.Time".as("Epoch"))
result.show(false)


+----+---------+-----+
|Time|Type     |Epoch|
+----+---------+-----+
|0   |New Epoch|0    |
|2   |Fo       |0    |
|3   |Bar      |0    |
|11  |New Epoch|11   |
|12  |Baz      |11   |
+----+---------+-----+
```