# how to set a increment id over set of rows with respect to a col value in spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset, apache-spark-2.0

Hi i have a dataset looks like :

my input :

```
+----------+----------------+
|  id      |  flag          |
+----------+----------------|
|  1       | false          |  
+----------+----------------|
|  2       | true           | 
+----------+----------------|
|  3       | false          |
+----------+----------------|
|  4       | true           |  
+----------+----------------|
|  5       | false          |
+----------+----------------|
|  6       | false          |  
+----------+----------------|
|  7       | true           |
+----------+----------------+
```

output :

```
+----------+----------------+----------------------------+
|  id      |  flag          |  new_col                   |
+----------+---------------------------------------------+
|  1       | false          |      1                     |
+----------+---------------------------------------------+
|  2       | true           |      1                     |
+----------+----------------+----------------------------+
|  3       | false          |      3                     |
+----------+----------------+----------------------------+
|  4       | true           |      3                     |
+----------+----------------+----------------------------+
|  5       | false          |      5                     |
+----------+----------------+----------------------------+
|  6       | false          |      6                     |
+----------+----------------+----------------------------+
|  7       | true           |      6                     |
+----------+----------------+----------------------------+
```

each false value will change the new_col value to its id and so on...
any help please ?

Comment: that is my case i want to know if its possible to make that using any spark window function if yes can i have any idea ?.i think the example that i put is clear to explain the problem

Comment: You could use Window functions but then you will have to work with a single partition which will impact the performance. If your dataset is small, I'd suggest going for a windowed solution.

Comment: You can check it out! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47643416/compute-a-value-using-multiple-preceding-rows/47644505#47644505

Comment: my dataset size about 3000 row.i do not found any of spark window functions (lead,lag,rank,...) can solve my problem.can you help me in any suggested function or example

Comment: thanks you all i will check @nabongs answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a dataset of smaller size, you could do the following:

1. Use `when`-`otherwise` to with `withColumn` to create a new column which will take the value of `id` or `null` depending on the value of `flag` which in SQL is equivalent to:

```sql
CASE WHEN FLAG = 'TRUE' THEN ID ELSE NULL END AS NEW_COL
```

2. Then use [`coalesce`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#coalesce-scala.collection.Seq-) to replace all the nulls with [`last`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#last-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-boolean-) over a Window to get the last non-null value:

```scala
df.show
//+---+-----+
//| id| flag|
//+---+-----+
//|  1|false|
//|  2| true|
//|  3| true|
//|  4| true|
//|  5|false|
//|  6| true|
//|  7| true|
//+---+-----+

//Defining a Window over which we will call the function
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

//No partitionBy clause so all the data will move to a single partition
//You'll also get a warning related to that
val w = Window.orderBy($"id")

//The value of `id` will be the same where `flag` is `false`
//last will be called over the window to fill the null values   
df.withColumn("new_col" , when($"flag" === lit(false) , $"id").otherwise(null))
  .withColumn("new_col" , coalesce($"new_col" , last($"new_col", true).over(w) ) )
  .show   
//+---+-----+-------+
//|id |flag |new_col|
//+---+-----+-------+
//|1  |false|1      |
//|2  |true |1      |
//|3  |true |1      |
//|4  |true |1      |
//|5  |false|5      |
//|6  |true |5      |
//|7  |true |5      |
//+---+-----+-------+
```

Comment: very good one :) it would help if you explain what coalesce does

Comment: No @sandev he is using inbuilt funtion https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#coalesce-scala.collection.Seq- and you are talking about another coalesce

Comment: @RameshMaharjan Thanks, explanation added.

Comment: what if we have multilple false value after each other nad true after them how the true one can take the last false one id ?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to go with `rdd` way then you can *pass all the data to one executor* and do the *for loop* as below

```
df.rdd.coalesce(1).mapPartitions(iterator => {
  var y = "1"
  for (x <- iterator) yield {
    val id = x.getAs[String]("id")
    val flag = x.getAs[Boolean]("flag")
    if(flag == false){
      y = id
      newdf(id, flag, y)
    }else{
      newdf(id, flag, y)
    }
  }
}).toDF()
```

and for that you would need a *case class*

```
case class newdf(id:String, flag:Boolean, new_id:String)
```

You *can do without case class too* but I prefer to use *case class*

Comment: can i  use dataset.mapPartitions... directly without coalesce(1)

Comment: that wouldn't give you correct results if you are processing in a cluster. coalesce is done to transfer data to be in one partition

Comment: from performance point of view which answer is better using mapPartition or the answer given above

Comment: test them and analyze them. and do accept one which performs better. Its all upto you